I'm really struggling to understand why my project 'Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar' '
I'm a nooby here and although I've spent the last 3 evenings trying to resolve this issue I've lost all hope of me trying to sort this by myself...
I'm trying to use 'Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar' as a parent to a custom style however I can't get Android Studio Koala Feature Drop to resolve the symbol.
Here are some copy/pastes of my project so far:
build.gradle.kts(:app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.training"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.training"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidxAppCompat)
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)


}


libs.versions.toml

[versions]
agp = "8.6.0"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.5"
activityCompose = "1.9.2"
composeBom = "2024.09.01"
material3 = "1.3.0"
androidxAppCompat = "1.7.0"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name ="material3", version.ref = "material3" }
androidxAppCompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "androidxAppCompat"}

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }


themes.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Training" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">

        <!-- Primary and accent colors -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryVariant</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>

    </style>
</resources>

AndroidManifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Training"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Training">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


Please could you have a quick look and give me a nudge in the right direction?
I've tried every answer that I can find in the docs, google search etc... clean, rebuild, gradle sync, restart AS, different depenency, additional dependency etc etc

The Material3 theme you're trying to use is from the Material Components library, which is for Views, and which you don't have configured as a dependency, thus the error. You appear to be setting up a Compose project, though, and those usually use one of the base system themes, like android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar, because Compose handles theme stuff in code. If you are doing a Compose project, you shouldn't need Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar.
